# Not able to display uploaded image using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am trying to upload image into mySQL database and display it on a jsp using struts2 tags. I am able to upload image on to the server but not able to show it in jsp. I searched in Internet and did all possible changes that I can do. Still I was not able to show the image on jsp which gave me a new doubt whether the image  is uploaded or not. Please go through my code and tell me where I am doing mistake. Thankyou.

Here is my jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<div id="form_container" align="center">
    <s:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        .
        .
        <s:file         name="image"                    label="Retinal Image"/>
        <s:submit       value="upload"/>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

Action class.

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, uploadBean.getImageFileName());

System.out.println("fileToCreate="+fileToCreate.getName());
FileUtils.copyFile(uploadBean.getImage(), fileToCreate);
Map session     = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();      
session.put("image",filePath);
//some code for keeping image in database which is showing as success as I can see blob in the table after this code was run
```

UploadBean.java

```
private File    image;
private String  imageContentType;
private String  imageFileName;
//getters and setters
```

Finally this image has to be shown in the success page. 
Uploaded.jsp

```
<s:property value="imageFileName"/>
<s:property value="imageContentType"/>
<s:property value="image"/>
<img src="#session.image"/>
```

My struts.xml is

```
<action name="upload"       class="com.ActionClasses.UploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">3145728</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg, image/jpg</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success"  type="tiles">   uploaded    </result>
    <result name="error"    type="tiles">   upload      </result>
    <result name="input"    type="tiles">   upload      </result>
</action>
```

Please tell me the mistake that I did. Thankou.

Comment: plz post ur struts.xml too

Comment: You are putting only filepath inside session object. Is it having file name too? Check its value before putting inside session object.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I made the change you said. But still image is not being displayed.

Comment: can u post the value of filePath variable? and ur project structure where u r saving this image.

Comment: Path of my file is /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/DReST/O15091400007. I am able to find the image in the path which is being printed from the action class.

Comment: O15091400007 is this file name or directory name? plz post complete path with file name and extention too

Comment: O15091400007 is the filename. In my previous comment I wrote filepath+imageFileName

Answer (score 0):

Image path should be relative path .ie relativePath\+filename.ext

```
string  imageRelPath=<relativePath>+"\\"+uploadBean.getImageFileName()

session.put("image"imageRelPath)
```

Example : Supose you uploaded the file abc.jpg at image folder

String filePath=servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

```
filePath=filePath+"\\"image;
```

then your "imageRelPath" will be

```
imageRelPath="./image/abc.jpg"
```

In your case it will

```
imageRelPath="./abc.jpg" i.e 

session.put("image","./"+uploadBean.getImageFileName());
```

as you are not storing at any subfolder

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still i am not able to show the image in the jsp.

Comment: Can you give the value for "filePath" and "uploadBean.getImageFileName()" ?

Comment: /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/DReST/O15091400007. This is filePath+uploadBean.getImageFileName()

Comment: First think you are missing extension of the file while saving of the image i.e .jpg , png etc. Second if your Application name is "DReST" then give path "./O15091400007.<extension>". If still unable to get the image . It in Chrome , press F12 and inspect image element chrome will show you image developer console. The right click on src and click open in new tab. This will give the exact refering path of the image by chrome and compare it with correct path.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't which type of image is being uploaded by the user. uploadBean.getImageContentType() is giving the output like image/jpeg. Should I keep some if conditions for concatenating the image extension.

Comment: With curiosity I am asking you one question. Why you kept your username as 'SeeTheC'? I am asking this because I maintained some documents with this same name before 3 years.

Comment: <s:property value="image"/> this is also not working. This is printing some '.tmp' filename

Comment: Yes. use the content type. And <s:property value="image"/> will not works as "iamge" type is File and you are trying pring object value.

Comment: SeeTheC is my alias name , I use it various C-Competition

Comment: If I do like that a broken image icon is being displayed. But image is not being displayed even now after attaching the file extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61248/discussion-between-user130004-and-seethec).